# Change the number of the partition from sda1 to sda2

Tags: linux, partition, fdisk

I have a disk with two partitions: sda1 and sda2. I would like change the number of sda1 to sda2 and sda2 to sda1.

It's possible but I don't remember the procedure. i.e. My first partition will be sda2 and the second sda1, so I need to specify a manual order, not an automatic ordering like in fdisk -> x -> f.

How can I change the order? Links to manuals or tutorials are also welcome.

Thanks.

The reason: I have an application that needs to read data from sda1 but the data is in sda2. Changing the partition table is the fastest fix for this issue. The system isn't critical but I don't want to keep the system halted for too much time.

**Update**: the fdisk version of OpenBSD includes this functionality.

Comment: As it is generally a bad idea to do what you ask for, please describe *why* you want that.

Comment: I have backups, don't worry :)

Comment: Ok, you have been warned and want to play, so here goes... :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

FYI, **it is a bad idea** and you can lose everything. If you still want to do it, here are the steps:

1. *Don't* do it. If this doesn't help, then:
2. Use the `sfdisk` tool:
   First, make a backup of the partition table using

   ```
   sfdisk -d /dev/sda > sda.out
   ```

   Then go for it:

   ```
   sfdisk /dev/sda -O sda-partition-sectors.save
   ```

   You will see something like this

   ```
   Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ...
   OK

   Disk /dev/sda: 1018 cylinders, 124 heads, 62 sectors/track
   Old situation:
   Units = cylinders of 3936256 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

      Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
   /dev/sda1          0+      5       6-     23063+  83  Linux
   /dev/sda2          6    1017    1012    3890128   83  Linux
   /dev/sda3          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
   /dev/sda4          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
   Input in the following format; absent fields get a default value.
   <start> <size> <type [E,S,L,X,hex]> <bootable [-,*]> <c,h,s> <c,h,s>
   Usually you only need to specify <start> and <size> (and perhaps <type>).

   /dev/sda1 :
   ```

Now it is asking you to give the new details for the 'sda1' partition. So you have to give the numbers of sda2 here. So, I put '6 1012' here and press Enter:

```
    /dev/sda1 :6 1012
    /dev/sda1          6    1017    1012    3890128   83  Linux
    /dev/sda2 :
```

Now **check** if the numbers printed after you pressed Enter are **exactly** the same as those printed earlier for sda2. If it is okay, continue with giving the new numbers for sda2:

```
    /dev/sda2 :0
    /dev/sda2          0+      5       6-     23063+  83  Linux
    /dev/sda3 :
```

This time it was enough to enter "0" in my case - but you have to make sure the numbers aren't messed up in yours.

Next, continue with the other partitions in the same manner. If you already reached the end of the disk, pressing Enter is enough. Finally, check again that all the numbers are okay and save the partition table (or not). If you messed something up, have a look at `man sfdisk` and the descriptions of '-d', '-O' and '-I' options.

Notice also, that once you've made the crazy changes, you might need to run 'sync' so that the partitions are re-read before you try to mount them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right, this is scary :) .

Comment: Wonderfully evil. What happens if the numbers aren't the same? Give up and repartition? (That's what I did)

Comment: @supervacuo [Testisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) might help you then. Search for `testdisk` package in your distro's software database.

Comment: @supervacuo If the numbers aren't the same then your new partitions aren't in the same place as the old partitions and you will potentially corrupt them. If you don't do anything else to the disk then you can restore the partition table that you hopefully backed up before starting and try again. If not then you'd better hope that the correct numbers are still on your console somewhere, or that you can remember the exact size and location of your partitions and work the numbers out.

Answer (score 52):

I just did this in an easier way:

```
# sfdisk --dump /dev/sdb > sdb.bkp
```

leave a copy for safety

```
# cp sdb.bkp sdb.new
```

now edit sdb.new changing ONLY the lines order and partition numbers, as in my case:

from

```
# partition table of /dev/sdb
unit: sectors

/dev/sdb1 : start=  1026048, size=975747120, Id=83
/dev/sdb2 : start=     2048, size=   204800, Id=83
/dev/sdb3 : start=   206848, size=   819200, Id= b
/dev/sdb4 : start=        0, size=        0, Id= 0
```

to

```
# partition table of /dev/sdb
unit: sectors

/dev/sdb1 : start=     2048, size=   204800, Id=83
/dev/sdb2 : start=   206848, size=   819200, Id= b
/dev/sdb3 : start=  1026048, size=975747120, Id=83
/dev/sdb4 : start=        0, size=        0, Id= 0
```

then throw it back to the disk partition table?

```
# sfdisk /dev/sdb < sdb.new
```

My numbering sequence was mangled after I shrank & shifted right the only partition (sdb1) to add two smaller partitions at the start of the disk using `gparted`.

If the last command does not work, as in my case, change it for:

```
# sfdisk --no-reread --force /dev/sdb < sdb.new
```

Comment: This worked for me and I didn't end up needing that 2nd command.

Comment: For me as well, thanks ;) ... Note make sure all your partition are unmounted before commands

Comment: This worked perfectly for my USB. I use Rufus to boot FAT32 partition to NTFS partition with EFI so I can reinstall Windows 10 if there are issues. However, I have an extra partition for getting files from my PS4. This allowed me to set that partition as sdb1 so PS4 sees it as the first option. The only thing I can nitpick about is replacing `-d` with `--dump` argument just to make it clear what the command is doing. Apart from that, I believe this should be the best answer for it's simplicity.

Comment: Hi, I'm from the far future. Linux works more or less exactly the same way, and this worked for me even though I did it with a live, mounted drive on a headless Raspberry Pi, like an idiot would do. It was still fine.

Comment: Works like a charm! After cloning ESXi OS I got the following error: "Bank 5: not found Bank 6: invalid configuration". After doing some research I found out that ESXi expects the two 250.0 MB partitions to be numbered 5 and 6. I've applied your method using a LiveCD and the problem was solved in less than 5 minutes!

Answer (score 15):

All the existing solutions look very safe, but as a result quite complicated.

I wanted to reorder ***all*** my partitions so they'd be in order.

If you are more experienced, have non-essential or backed-up data and are happy to fix any issues as a result, you can boot from a Live CD and [do it this way](https://journalxtra.com/linux/how-to-reorder-linux-drive-partition-numbers/):

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdX
```

then:

- `x` to enter Expert Mode
- `f` to fix the drive order (possibly `i` to ignore any warnings if required)
- `r` to return to normal mode
- `w` to write changes to the disk and exit

### Additional

I don't recall the exact next steps as I only did it once and haven't retested, but as I was also moving the install I also mounted the partitions and [copied all files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44967/difference-between-cp-r-and-cp-a):

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sda4
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/sda4
sudo mkdir /mnt/sda5
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/sda5
date;cp -a /mnt/sda4/* /mnt/sda5;date
```

And then got the partition ids:

```
sudo blkid
```

and updated the following to reflect the new partitions UUID values:

- `/mnt/sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
- `/mnt/sda5/etc/fstab`

I then [updated GRUB2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd/145246#145246):

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/sda5 /dev/sda
```

Comment: This is the best and safest answer

Comment: Obviously this only works if you want the partition numbers to correspond to their order, but if that's the case, this is truly the easiest and probably the safest way.

Comment: If you just want to reorder partitions so they are in order, do `sfdisk -r`. That's enough.

Comment: This does nothing if you have a single partition that does not have the number 1 and want to rename, e.g., /dev/sda3 to /dev/sda1.

Comment: Fastest and safest answer. Reordering all partitions using the fdisk commands here shown took me like, 4 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

I just discovered a surprisingly easy solution to this problem. Say you have only one partition left named `/dev/sda3`. You want it to be called `/dev/sda1`. Open `gdisk`, convert the partition table to GPT, write, and exit. Then open it again, press sort (this will change the GPT number to 1), and then convert the GPT back to MBR via the expert options.

Comment: This seems dangerous. gdisk warns against this: `converting MBR to GPT format in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE!`. Moreover, it is not clear which expert option converts from GPT to MBR.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to rewrite the drive partition table to reverse the order, which is a bit risky to do. If I were you I would fix the problem that makes you want to swap the order of device names and leave the partitions alone.

For instance if you have a script that needs to run on both machines and you want it to access the same device, then create a link in a different directory (not /dev) which is the same name on both servers, but links to /dev/sda1 on one, and /dev/sda2 on the other.

You can use any partition editor (`fdisk` or `cfdisk`) to edit the partitions but you need to either write down the current settings or take a photo of the screen. Delete the two partitions, and then create them manually, specifying all the correct values. Boot the system with a LiveCD to do this.

Comment: I can't change anything. My system is a Xen DomU and the problem is in the Dom0. I could recreate the order of partitions but is more complex in my situation. But anyway, I would like know how change the order.

Answer (score 2):

First off, this whole thing is an exercise in trying your best to break things, but anyway, here's another approach you can try.

*Note: You didn't mention where you boot from, and this solution, and no other one at the time I am writing this, are addressing what you would have to do to get LILO or GRUB to work properly.*

`/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` are block devices (8,1) and (8,2). You can try using `mknod` to simply swap the two.

```
telinit 1
(...)
rm -f /dev/sda{1,2}; mknod /dev/sda1 b 8 2; mknod /dev/sda2 b 8 1
chmod 640 /dev/sda{1,2}; chown root:disk /dev/sda{1,2}
reboot
```

Just remember that this swapping will happen only after your partition containing `/dev/` is loaded upon boot, so the `initrd` will still have the "correct" ones unless you fix it there too (exercise for the reader - will `mkinitrd` copy the strangeness?) *This also doesn't address SELinux contexts.*

Comment: The bootloader isn't a problem :) . Thanks for the solution but I need change the order in the partition table, not in the system.

Comment: That's not going to work on any system that uses udev, and it would only help if the application read from a file called `/dev/sda` (as opposed to reading the disk directly).

Comment: Both - agreed. The whole question IMHO is an exercise in pain. I wasn't sure about the `udev` stuff; apparently the first system I `ssh`d into didn't have it.

Answer (score 1):

## - Editing partitions /dev/sda3 to /dev/sda2 in terminal as root -

1. Backup partition table

   sfdisk -d /dev/sda > sda.bkp
2. Copy partition table backup to the new partition table

   cp sda.bkp sda.new
3. Edit new partition table

   gedit sda.new

[image]

Save, close

4. Reinstall the new partition table

   sfdisk --no-reread -f /dev/sda < sda.new
5. Reboot computer

Comment: Although this is doable, I'd recommend the [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php)

Comment: I think you can do better than a screenshot of a text editor with a non-monospace font, a visible insertion point, and visible spellchecker errors.