# Does cp -a refresh existing files, overwrite or skip

Tags: shell, cp

If I use `cp` in archive mode e.g

```
cp -a /my_old_directory/* /new_location/my_new_directory/
```

to replicate a directory structure and all that is in it.

If I then run the same command again will any changed files be refreshed or over-written or skipped?

(I know `rsync` is more advanced at this kind of thing, I'm just curious about `cp -a` as I can't find any description of what it actually does in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cp will overwrite all files.

what you are looking for if you do not want that behavior is the rsync command.

the -a option just means it will preserve the source file metadata, like creation time, owner, access mode and such..

Answer (score 1):

Existing files will be over-written, as somewhat *implied* in [gilles'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) answer to [Difference between cp -r and cp -a](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44967/difference-between-cp-r-and-cp-a).