# How can I move my /boot partition?

Tags: partition, hard-disk

My /boot partition is at the end of my mechanical hard drive and I have free space at the start that I want to move it to, but there are a bunch of partitions in the way. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GParted`.

First, boot from a live USB or disc. I recommend Ubuntu since it comes with GParted already on the Live portion. Load up the live portion of the usb/disc by 'trying' ubuntu.

Once it is all finished loading, you should see a familiar Ubuntu screen. Click on the Menu and search for GParted, and run it.

You should see something like this:
[image: GParted]
You can then right-click the partition you want to copy, and select Copy in the menu, and then in the free space you have, right click and click Paste. GParted will ask you where exactly do you want to put it. Customize your partitioning and click Paste.
[image: Confirmation for Pasting a partition.]

Now you can delete the other partition and click Apply, since it will only delete the partition after copying it.
[image: Pending Operations for GParted]

And there you go, you have successfully moved a partition.

Comment: Is there any way to make a partition have a certain number (eg. sda3) when I copy the partition?

Comment: I found this ask with a checked answer that solved what you want to do. Not sure how advanced you are. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18752