# How do I create on a USB storage device, a partition 1 of exFat, with data files and the loadable iso, and partition 2 with the UEFI bootable Grub2?

Tags: partition, grub2

**Update 2**

Okay, I've managed to get a working live USB with Grub2.

First I created created a `gpt` partition table with GParted and created the following partitions:

- `exfat` - [Remaining space] Live CD ISOs and files. (Created with gnome-disk-utility since GParted doesn't support it.)
- `ntfs` - [5.50 GiB] Extracted Windows 10 recovery ISO files.
- `fat16` - [100 MiB] Grub2.

I followed [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18752/change-the-number-of-the-partition-from-sda1-to-sda2/90224#90224) answer on how to change the partition number order just so they were in the correct order. I used fat16 in hoping my PS4 couldn't see it so that it could auto mount the exfat partition without being asked which partition to mount - it didn't work. I'm only aware that fat16 and fat32 are the only compatible Grub2 UEFI boot-able partitions.

Then to install Grub2. I mounted the partition were I wanted to install Grub2 were "GRUB2" is the label given under GParted and "user" is my Xubuntu account name.

```
sudo grub-install --removable --boot-directory=/media/user/GRUB2/boot --efi-directory=/media/user/GRUB2
```

Then I create the grub.cfg under `/media/user/GRUB2/boot/grub/grub.cfg` with the following entries.

```
menuentry "Lubuntu Boot Recovery Live CD (AMD64)" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod exfat
    insmod search_fs_uuid

    set iso=/iso/boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso
    search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid 92AE-07D5

    loopback loop ($root)$iso
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper file=/preseed/lubuntu.seed iso-scan/filename=$iso noprompt noeject
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}

menuentry "Windows 10 Installer on SDB2 (AMD64)" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    insmod search_fs_uuid
    insmod chain

    search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid 13B187F260B1ACD6
    chainloader ($root)/efi/boot/bootx64.efi
}

menuentry "Xubuntu Live CD (AMD64)" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod exfat
    insmod search_fs_uuid

    set iso=/iso/xubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso
    search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid 92AE-07D5

    loopback loop ($root)$iso
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper file=/preseed/lubuntu.seed iso-scan/filename=$iso noprompt noeject
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
```

Took a while researching but from my understanding.

- `insmod` - This is used to load the following module. Presumably, I don't think these are needed in 2.02> but I added them just in case. I found a handy list [here](https://www.linux.org/threads/understanding-the-various-grub-modules.11142/).
- `set` - Is used to set a variable.
- `search` - This searches for certain criteria such as matching directory, UUID of the partition, partition name, etc and stores it in a variable under --set.

I'm not entirely sure how or what loopback, linux, initrd, preseed and chainloader actual functionality are. But I copied the file paths but the extension maybe different or may not have an extension.

---

So far I've got everything I want working but I presume running a Windows 10 ISO from an ISO file isn't possible without a more complicated script. This is a code snippet I've got so far for the menu entry but it doesn't work.

```
menuentry "Windows 10 Installer (AMD64) (ISO) (Doesn't work)" --class windows --class os {
    # Load module to be able to read GPT partition table.
    insmod part_gpt

    # Load module to read the partition that ISO is stored.
    insmod exfat

    # Load module to find partition with UUID.
    insmod search_fs_uuid

    # Load module to chain load to another EFI.
    insmod chain

    # Set UUID of partition that has ISO image and store it in variable.
    set uuid="92AE-07D5"
    search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid $uuid

    # Set ISO Directory.
    set iso=/iso/win10-1909-english-x64.iso

    # Mount ISO.
    loopback loop ($root)$iso

    # Boot ISO.
    #chainloader (loop)/efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot.efi
    chainloader (loop)+1
}
```

I've tried `#chainloader (loop)/efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot.efi` uncommented before `chainloader (loop)+1` but to not success.

All that's left of the question is: How do I boot Windows 10 Installer ISO to boot from a ISO file?

Comment: Welcome! (Maybe) I will write a full answer, but for starters, you can partition your usb into one small fat partition to install grub, an (ntfs, ext4) partition to store the linux isos, and final partition to store the **contents** of the windows iso. Then in your grub configuration you just need to point to the partitions.

Comment: For now grub 2.04 does not work, but 2.02 does. See: 2.04 Out of memory error loop mount
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1851311 UEFI only boots /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. But grub can chain or configfile to other installs. Note sure how you get Windows /EFI/Microsoft folder to chain into from grub without an install of Windows. I created a Windows (only) bootable ISO and Windows installer split .wim file in ISO to allow it to fit on FAT32 partition.https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines

Comment: I've just ran `grub-install --version` and it's currently 2.02 so I don't think it got pushed to Xubuntu 18.04 yet. I should be fine running ISO from UEFI mode since my laptop doesn't support legacy booting. So if I understand correctly. P1 exFat for data, P2 NTFS of Windows ISO extracted contents, P3 for ISO and Grub2?